# How do I center text in the upper third of amp-story?

Tags: layout, grid, centering, amp-story

**the problem**
 - text assigned to the upper third of an amp-story grid-area appears in the upper left hand corner.  I want the text to appear in the middle of the grid of the upper third.

How would I center the text horizontally and vertically in the upper third grid area?

**grid areas**

- grid-area="upper-third"
- grid-area="middle-third"
- grid-area="lower-third"

**sample code**

```
<amp-story-grid-layer template="thirds">
  <h1 grid-area="upper-third">element 1</h1>
  <p grid-area="lower-third">element 2</p>
</amp-story-grid-layer>
```

Comment: Could you please share full code in [codepen](https://codepen.io/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Are you asking me to create an entire amp-story to show the problem? You can see how to create an amp-story here https://www.ampproject.org/docs/getting_started/visual_story/setting_up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `align-self` and `justify-self` attributes, as follows:

```
<amp-story-grid-layer template="thirds">
  <h1 grid-area="upper-third" align-self="center" justify-self="center">element 1</h1>
  <p grid-area="lower-third" align-self="center" justify-self="center">element 2</p>
</amp-story-grid-layer>
```